# Understanding send method of Inbox

Tags: java, scala, akka

I'm reading the [akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/untyped-actors.html#The_Inbox) and now I'm at the section about `Inbox`. Here's what is said there:

> The `send` method wraps a normal `tell` and supplies the internal actor’s
>   reference as the sender.

But what's the difference? When using `tell` this way:

```
ActorRef aRef1;
ActorRef aRef2;
//init the references
aRef1.tell(aRef2, "Message");
```

we can get the sender in the onRecieve method like this:

```
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Sender: " + getSender().path().name());
}
```

What's the actual benefit of `send` in comparison to just `tell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of an [`Inbox`](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4/akka/actor/Inbox.html) is to have

> an actor-like object which is interrogated from the outside.

It's not meant to be used within an actor. It's for external systems that have access to the actor system/context and want to send a message to an actor.

The method [`send`](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4/akka/actor/Inbox.html#send-akka.actor.ActorRef-java.lang.Object-) documentation states

> Have the internal actor act as the sender of the given message which
>   will be sent to the given target. This means that should the target
>   actor reply then those replies will be received by this `Inbox`.

This allows an external component to act as if it was part of the actor system and [receive](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4/akka/actor/Inbox.html#receive-scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration-) messages from actors. Unfortunately, the price to pay for this is that `receive` is blocking.

Comment: But we can specify no timeout and receive will return immediately.

Comment: @user3663882 The method expects a `FiniteDuration` argument. You can provide `FiniteDuration#Zero()`, but if a reply hasn't been received yet, the method will throw a `TimeoutException`.